# Already running Mongo db start up issue in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I have issue with Mongo DB  start up in ubuntu 14.04 64 bit,its working fine when i installed first time but suddenly from now when i type mongo in ubuntu terminal its showing error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: test
2015-11-26T11:59:03.888+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-11-26T11:59:03.889+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

I tried many solution 
i.e

1.deleting lock files, and restart mongo,

2.Change bind ip to 0.0.0.0 in mongod.conf

but my issue still not resolved.

Comment: Is mongo server actually runnig? You can confirm by typing ps -ef | grep mongo

Comment: No its not running, even  when i stop mongo server by  typing                         sudo service mongod stop its showing unknown instance

Comment: See the log files why its not starting up. By default the log file is stored at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: i see the log file its showing  error                                                                   2015-11-26T12:18:05.058+0530 I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2015-11-26T12:18:05.078+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2015-11-26T12:18:05.078+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2015-11-26T12:18:05.078+0530 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure

Comment: remove /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock file and restart your server. Check if it works now

Comment: there is no file available with this name. i have two at location /var/tmp/  with same name as "mongod.conf.swp" ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute the following command to grep process id of mongod to determine if mongo service is running or not

```
pgrep mongod
```

If process id exists then please follow the steps as mentioned below

(a) Kill existing mongod process using following command

```
sudo kill -9 [process_id]
```

(b) Start mongod process using

```
sudo mongod --noauth --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Comment: No process id found in my case. is there any other option

Comment: i run only second command can you describe what is the issue, and i run same command on ubuntu 12.04 32 bit it facing same problem.

Comment: @NikhiK.Bansal Please try to issue the following command to remove lock file  sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

Comment: According to MongoDB documentation MongoDB keeps a lock file while it's running. It creates this file when it is started, and deletes it when it's stopped. When the computer crashes (or MongoDB crashes, e.g. via kill), this file is not deleted, and thus the database does not start. The existence of this file indicates unclean shutdown of MongoDB.